# Passing scope as parameter into function to be saved

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, parameters

I have two functions in my controller found below.

```
$scope.formatPaymentDates = function() {
  $scope.formatDate($scope.payment.due_date);

  $scope.formatDate($scope.payment.date);
};


$scope.formatDate = function(attr) {
  if (attr) {
    var split_date = attr.split("-");

    if (split_date[0].length == 4) {
      attr = split_date[1] + "-" + split_date[2] + "-" + split_date[0];
    }  else {
      attr = split_date[2] + "-" + split_date[0] + "-" + split_date[1];
    }
  }
};
```

The problem is that the function formatDate only sets the scope variable attribute and does not save it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, strings and numbers are passed by value, while objects are passed by reference. You should pass an object as the parameter.

Or, as @faby mentioned, return the value:

```
$scope.formatPaymentDates = function() {
  $scope.payment.due_date = $scope.formatDate($scope.payment.due_date);
  $scope.payment.date = $scope.formatDate($scope.payment.date);
};


$scope.formatDate = function(attr) {
  var result;
  if (attr) {
    var split_date = attr.split("-");

    if (split_date[0].length == 4) {
      result = split_date[1] + "-" + split_date[2] + "-" + split_date[0];
    }  else {
      result = split_date[2] + "-" + split_date[0] + "-" + split_date[1];
    }
  }
  return result;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you aren't returning any result from your formatDate  function.
You are manipulating your variable inside the function and then destroy it.

try this

```
    $scope.formatDate = function(attr) {
      if (attr) {
        var split_date = attr.split("-");

        if (split_date[0].length == 4) {
          attr = split_date[1] + "-" + split_date[2] + "-" + split_date[0];
        }  else {
          attr = split_date[2] + "-" + split_date[0] + "-" + split_date[1];
        }
    return attr;
      }
return null
    };
```

and then

```
$scope.formatPaymentDates = function() {
  $scope.payment.due_date= $scope.formatDate($scope.payment.due_date);

  $scope.payment.date=$scope.formatDate($scope.payment.date);
};
```

Comment: If the `attr` paramter was an object, it would work, since all objects are passed by reference in JS. But it appears to be a string, which is passed by value.

Comment: I would have never thought of that. Thanks.

Comment: @MatthiasDailey I know that in theory what you say is true. The facts show the opposite instead. I invite you to give it a try and you will always see that the object variables behave as if they are passed by value.

Comment: @faby, maybe you're referring to passing object's parameters which evaluate to numbers and strings. But I assure you, in JavaScript, objects are always passed by reference. http://jsfiddle.net/5E8eg/